# If all Threat is removed before one player takes a turn in a round, does that player still need to block hits?

Tags: wushu

Some background: We're in a group with 5 + myself, so Threats are sometimes eliminated before certain players act. A player narrates their actions, rolls, removes Threat, and passes turn. However, sometimes we finish the round before some players have acted.

The rules for [Wushu](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/143146/Wushu-Black-Belt-Edition) seem straightforward:

> 5. Threats score 1 hit per round on each Hero;

However, it runs counter to my intuition for the game's telos of high-flying action to force the players who act after the last Threat has been removed to narrate themselves doing nothing but half-heartedly blocking some flying bits of robot ninja.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Players *all* narrate their actions for the round, *then* you roll.

The Black Belt edition you link includes an example of a round, abbreviated below.

> You: "The Governor takes hold of your arm..."
>
> Julie: "Lying down, I have enough room to draw my sword! I extend
> the blade so it impales the far wall, then drive one foot into the
> near wall, suspending myself over empty air."
>
> Mark: "Which is right about the time the engineers compensate for
> the broken valve and the train starts accelerating again."
>
> You decide that everyone’s earned at least 6 dice by this point, **so
> it’s time to roll.**
>
> (summary of player/Director rolls follows)

Emphasis mine.